# Hayes AT command support on Android

Tags: android, linux

A current product I work on supports standard modem AT commands over the serial link. Commands such as ATD, ATH, ATV, ATQ ATE etc to either get information from the device or seti info on the device.

The device also supports dial-up PPP connection which is typically preceded by some AT commands when initiated from the PC - ATD for e.g.

We are looking at creating a similar device using Android and I searched whether Android or Linux support Hayes modem AT commands over the serial interface such as RS232 or USB and am unable to find such a layer or component.

On Android RIL page I see it says that, "Android provides a reference Vendor RIL, using the Hayes AT command set, that you can use as a quick start for telephony testing and a guide for commercial vendor RILs". But I believe this may be for interfacing with the Baseband or Telephony layer. Is this also typically used with the serial interface where a DTE can issue AT commands and talk to the Android device ?

I also researched Linux and it does have a basic set of AT commands but they are not modem related and serve a different purpose  - e.g. atq  lists the user's pending jobs, atrm  deletes jobs, identified by their job number.

So I am looking to undestand, whether Android or the Linux kernel has a default AT command parser which supports the Hayes AT Command set, which can be accessed by a DTE connected to the Android device over a serial link.

I think this is a typical case for phones and other may have come across the same question or issue, but I have not found an answer searching on the Android forums.

---

adding more info to clarify my question as it seems from the answers, it wasnt very clear what I was asking

---

To clarify my question, I am not trying to issue AT commands from the Android phone. Rather I am looking to issue AT commands from a PC to an Android phone over a serial link such as RS232/USB/Bluetooth.

I am trying to understand if Android inherently supports AT commands and has an AT parser ?

For e.g. to establish a PPP link (dial-up connection) from Windows to a device that supports PPP, windows will first send some AT commands and finally the ATD (dial) command. The device responds with a CONNECT response, afterwhich it switches to online mode and a PPP link is established and IP data cab be sent between the PC and the device. Thus typically such devices (modems) by default are in AT mode. ATD is just one such command. There are several other AT commands supported by the device.

Now to develop a similar device using Android, I'd like to do that without significantly altering the Linux kernel or Andorid architecture and am looking to understand if a AT command parser which recognizes the standard set of AT commands is inhenrently supported by android.

To make my question clearer, consider the case where a PC for e.g. connects to a device (phone) using the BT DUNS (dialup networking) profile. The DUNS profile requires the phone to support i.e. parse and recognize certain AT commands such as AT&C, &D, &F, +GCAP, +GMI, +GMM, +GMR, ATA, D, E, H, L, M etc.

How does Android address this ? Does it have native support for reconizing and responding to such AT commands ?

thanks in advance!

Comment: did you got any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you like to send AT-commands via a serial communication from an Android device to your hardware - and get the responses back.

Basically one would implement a serial communication either via Bluetooth - or starting with level 12 using USB communication.

I have done quite extensive serial communication in both ways it it works quite well. The main problem so far has been that while Bluetooth serial-Adapters are quite expensive - the new USB-serial communication has flaws on certain devices.

The last time I tested Samsung Galaxy Tab, the USB driver's were not functional. On some other Android device there were no USB-drivers at all installed.

But once you have a working Android device serial communication (with or without using AT-commands) works fine

For more info you might like to check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html

Comment: Please see more info I added to the post to clarify my question. I am looking to send AT commands to the device and for it to recognize and process the AT commands.

Comment: OK - this is sth different. AFAIK there is no inherent support for AT-commands. You would have to write your parser&interpreter yourself, as well as the translation to the appropriate functions on Android system.

Comment: any leads on that what you posted here?

Answer (score 0):

On linux, there's the [chat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chat) command, which was typically used by the pppd demon. Then there's the classical [TCL expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm), which allows scripting. It has been ported to many languages, eg [expect for Java](http://code.google.com/p/expect4j/), [Python expect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html). I haven't used the latter two, but it looks as if you can use them as a library and don't have to call them as external programs.

It's a curious thing that the most advanced mobile phones still use the archaic Hayes AT command set instead of a proper API..